# Front coil spring broken and the part has been discontinued

Tags: suspension, repair, parts, infiniti

My son has a 1999 Infiniti Q45 that broke one of it's front coil springs.  It's near the bottom, so it still mostly works, but we want to fix it right.  However, we have looked at multiple online retailers and called several parts stores and junk yards in the area, but no one has a single replacement spring (or strut either, though his are typically sold separately).  Is there anyway to locate a compatible spring, even if it's not the exact part?  I have been trying to find the exact dimensions, but no one seems to have them.  One site might have said 8.2" diameter (inside? outside?), 19" long, but I can't find that site again now so I'm not sure.  Besides, nothing I've found in aftermarket parts seems anywhere near that big.  Is there anyway to resolve this, or is he just out of luck on this car?

Comment: Try internet salvage parts. I live near Houston and could not find a Nissan wheel in a junkyard. I had to go to an OK online site. Heat-treat of a spring is as important as dimensions so local manufacture is unlikely to match.

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous companies that can make springs to order, which may be worth talking to, for example - https://www.skegsprings.co.uk/

I don’t know anything about this example company, I just did a search on google.

A company like this will be able to make you a spring, or a matching pair, but may also be able to give you advice on common spring sizes.  It would be worth giving one a call.

You may even find that your coil springs are a common size that they have in stock.